# Microsoft.Office.Interop Range question

Tags: excel

I have

```
objSheet.Range("$A1:$A4") 'where  objSheet is Excel.Worksheet
```

Can someone tell me what "$A1:$A4" means? Is it merged cells? I have also seen something like:

```
objSheet.Range("$H1:$H1")
```

which makes no sense....

I am working on someone's code and MSDN is not extremely helpful on this class.

Answer (score 3):

$A1:$A4 means the 4 cells starting in column A row 1 through column A row 4.

The $ denotes an absolute reference rather than a relative one.
For help on the Range object see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978779%28office.12%29.aspx
 For help on range references see Excel Help on Range References